# Get the unique lines of second file in result of comparing two files

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I have two text files, and I want to read file1 line by line, searching for the same line in file2 and removing it from file2.

I have the pseudocode of:

```
for line in file1.txt
do
  sed search line and delete in file2.txt
done
```

Comment: not a single answer for the diff command yet.

Answer (score 8):

You could accomplish this with grep.

Here is an example:

```
$ echo localhost > local_hosts

$ grep -v -f local_hosts /etc/hosts
127.0.1.1       ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: More to the point, you *should* accomplish this with grep. Regex special characters in a line from `file1` would cause a lot of problems with `sed`, but `grep` has `-F` for that.

Answer (score 5):

Generally you want to keep the *lines in file2* that are not in file1 actually.

There are more possibilities of these,

```
comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2) -23
```

via join

```
join -v 1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

or via [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) which doesn't need to sort the files:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{lines[$0];next} !($0 in lines)' file2 file1
```

Comment: In this case I do want to remove the lines from file2 that are in file1. Sort wont work as that would disrupt the order of the lines in file2.

Comment: so the only 'awk' option would be as your expectation when I already included in my answer :  )

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this through some more internet searches. And using just grep too without needing to sort the file.

```
grep -Fvxf file2 file1
```

This will display the new information on screen which presents a problem since I wanted to remove what was in file2 from file1 and have a new file1. Since the above code worked, I just had to add to it to get what I wanted.

```
grep -Fvxf file2 file1 > tempfile && mv tempfile file1
```

That solves my problems. Maybe not the best way but it does work.